# I can't dispatch my actions as props (React & Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is how I use `connect`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
    // we'll call this in our component -> this.props.listingData
    listingData: state.locations.listingData,

    //we'll call this in out component -> this.props.formState
    formState: state.formStates.formState
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(locationActions, formStateActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(homePage);
```

Here is the button which I used:

```
<div onClick={this.stateToEntry} className="addButton">Add</div>
```

Here is the function to run:

```
stateToEntry() {
        this.props.actions.stateToEntry();//formStateActions.stateToEntry();//dispatch an action to update the Redux store state
        browserHistory.push('/location');//then redirect to the add/edit/delete page using browserHistory
    }
```

I'm getting the error that `this.props.actions.stateToEntry()` is not a function. What's happening here actually & how do I solve this problem?

**EDIT**:

Here is the log data:
[image]

In other words its just adding the `{}` around it. I've tried using `{formStateActions}` alone and it didn't work but `formStateActions` worked.

For @LazarevAlexandr's, here is my actioncreator for `formStateActions`:

```
export function stateToEntry() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_ENTRY, formState: 'entry-mode'};
}

export function stateToEdit() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_EDIT, formState: 'edit-mode'};
}

export function stateToDelete() {
    return { type: types.STATE_TO_DELETE, formState: 'delete-mode'};
}
```

My locationActions actioncreator is quite long so I'd rather not post it fully here. They are all functions, some are actioncreators which return actions and some returns a function for fetching data lists from an api.

Comment: Show please the code where you are importing `locationActions` and `formStateActions` and how you define them

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr as mentioned by @krvital in his answer, the problem lies at `bindActionCreators` because I tried to use 3 parameters when it should be 2 only. (well I still need to check the docs). Problem I have right now is that `bindActionCreators({action1}, dispatch)` doesn't work. However `bindActionCreators(action1, dispatch)` without the brackets work but this is just in the case of using 1 action or 1 parameter. I want to use multiple actions.

Comment: I've understood it, and made an assumption that something might be wrong with your `actionCreators`.

Comment: I've edited my post for your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindActionsCreators`  gets only two parameters, so if want to pass multiple actions sets try this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const actions = Object.assign({}, locationActions, formStateActions);
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
}
```

Comment: I get a parsing error when using `bindActionCreators({...locationActions, ...formStateActions}, dispatch)` but the parsing problem gets fixed when using `bindActionCreators({locationActions, formStateActions}, dispatch)`. I'm still getting the same error ->`this.props.actions.stateToEntry()` is not a function,

Comment: You need `babel-preset-stage2` for object rest spread, anyway you can try this `bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, locationActions, formStateActions), dispatch)`

Comment: Tried your suggestion using `Object.assign()`, it doesnt work. When I use `bindActionCreators(formStateActions, dispatch)` then it works. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to debug what you get when you do `Object.assign({}, locationActions, formStateActions)` it must be object with all of your actions inside. Try to console.log what is `locationActions`, is it object?

Comment: Its an object but I can't seem to make it read my actions. Do you have a way so to solve this?

Comment: show `console.log(Object.assign({}, locationActions, formStateActions))` and `locationActions file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117373/discussion-between-krvital-and-joshua-rajandiran).